# Determining the gem's list of files for the specification

Tags: ruby, rubygems, packaging, file-listing

I've always used `git` to determine which files should go into the gem package:

```
gem.files = `git ls-files`.split "\n"
```

Unfortunately, [this approach has recently proved to be inappropriate](https://github.com/matheusmoreira/acclaim/issues/6). I need a self-contained, pure-Ruby solution.

My first idea was to simply glob the entire directory, but that alone is likely to include unwanted files. So, after researching the problem, I came up with this:

```
# example.gemspec

directory = File.dirname File.expand_path __FILE__
dotfiles = %w(.gitignore .rvmrc)
ignore_file = '.gitignore'
file_list = []

Dir.chdir directory do
  ignored = File.readlines(ignore_file).map(&:chomp).reject { |glob| glob =~ /\A(#|\s*\z)/ }
  file_list.replace Dir['**/**'] + dotfiles
  file_list.delete_if do |file|
    File.directory?(file) or ignored.any? { |glob| File.fnmatch? glob, file }
  end
end

# Later...

gem.files = file_list
```

That seems a bit complex for a `gemspec`. It also does not fully support [`gitignore`'s pattern format](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html). It currently seems to work but I'd rather not run into problems later.

Is there a simpler but robust way to compute the gem's list of files? Most gems apparently use `git ls-files`, and the ones that don't either use a solution similar to mine or specify the files manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With Rake

The easiest solution depending on rake to  list all files from a directory, but exclude everything in the `.gitignore` file:

```rb
require 'rake/file_list'
Rake::FileList['**/*'].exclude(*File.read('.gitignore').split)
```

### RubyGems

Official rubygems solution, list and exclude manually:

```rb
require 'rake'
spec.files = FileList['lib/*.rb',
                      'bin/*',
                      '[A-Z]*',
                      'test/*'].to_a

# or without Rake...
spec.files = Dir['lib/*.rb'] + Dir['bin/*']
spec.files += Dir['[A-Z]*'] + Dir['test/**/*']
spec.files.reject! { |fn| fn.include? "CVS" }
```

### Bundler

Bundler solution, list manually:

```rb
s.files = Dir.glob("{lib,exe}/**/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).reject {|f| File.directory?(f) }
```

Note: rejecting directories is useless as gem will ignore them by default.

### Vagrant

Vagrant solution to mimic `git ls-files` and taking care of `.gitignore` in pure ruby:

```rb
  # The following block of code determines the files that should be included
  # in the gem. It does this by reading all the files in the directory where
  # this gemspec is, and parsing out the ignored files from the gitignore.
  # Note that the entire gitignore(5) syntax is not supported, specifically
  # the "!" syntax, but it should mostly work correctly.
  root_path      = File.dirname(__FILE__)
  all_files      = Dir.chdir(root_path) { Dir.glob("**/{*,.*}") }
  all_files.reject! { |file| [".", ".."].include?(File.basename(file)) }
  all_files.reject! { |file| file.start_with?("website/") }
  all_files.reject! { |file| file.start_with?("test/") }
  gitignore_path = File.join(root_path, ".gitignore")
  gitignore      = File.readlines(gitignore_path)
  gitignore.map!    { |line| line.chomp.strip }
  gitignore.reject! { |line| line.empty? || line =~ /^(#|!)/ }

  unignored_files = all_files.reject do |file|
    # Ignore any directories, the gemspec only cares about files
    next true if File.directory?(file)

    # Ignore any paths that match anything in the gitignore. We do
    # two tests here:
    #
    #   - First, test to see if the entire path matches the gitignore.
    #   - Second, match if the basename does, this makes it so that things
    #     like '.DS_Store' will match sub-directories too (same behavior
    #     as git).
    #
    gitignore.any? do |ignore|
      File.fnmatch(ignore, file, File::FNM_PATHNAME) ||
        File.fnmatch(ignore, File.basename(file), File::FNM_PATHNAME)
    end
  end
```

### Pathspec

Using pathspec gem `Match Path Specifications, such as .gitignore, in Ruby!`

See https://github.com/highb/pathspec-ruby

### References

Ref:
[Bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/e1c518363641208429f397170354054b3d28effd/bundler.gemspec#L37)
[Vagrant](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/89cf1e70c578169c22ef40a32c1849fd1e4d7365/vagrant.gemspec#L53-L84)
[RubyGems](https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files)
[Rake easy solution](http://shorts.jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2014/glob_a_directory_but_exclude_files_listed_in_gitignore/)

Answer (score 10):

Hi,

You can list all files of your project with pure Ruby:

```rb
gem.files = Dir['**/*'].keep_if { |file| File.file?(file) }
```

Or you can do it manually, this solution is used by [Ruby on Rails gems](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/strong_parameters.gemspec#L15):

```rb
gem.files = Dir['lib/**/*'] + %w(.yardopts Gemfile LICENSE README.md Rakefile my_gem.gemspec)
```

Comment: Note that Rubygems already ignores directories for you: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L306-L307 - just `Dir['**/*']` is probably fine for many projects.